# Wacom Bamboo CTH460L issues

Tags: 10.04, wacom, graphics-tablet

I recently bought a Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch CTH460L. I installed doctormo's PPA, however, the pen functionality didn't work and the touch was very glitchy (when I touched it, it immediately double clicked and began to drag elements in the screen).

I tried to configure it using the wacom-utility package in the Synaptic Package Manager (version 1.21-1) but that didn't work either. Then I followed [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562&page=63) (#621, written by aaaalex), and after some problems trying to restart Ubuntu (graphics related problems), the pen works fine (it could be better, though) but the touch functionality doesn't work anymore.

Currently I have installed xserver-xorg-input-wacom (1:0.10.11-0ubuntu7), wacom-dkms (0.8.10.2-1ubuntu1) and wacom-utility. The Wacom Utility only displays an "options" field under "Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4X5" but no other option to configure it.

What is the correct way to get this tablet working on Ubuntu 10.04?.

By the way, currently I can't start Ubuntu properly when the tablet is connected (in that case, Ubuntu start in low graphics mode). I need to connect it later.

**UPDATE**: I uninstalled xserver -xorg-input-wacom, and wacom-utility because one of them prevented Ubuntu to start normally. I only re-installed wacom-dkms 0.8.10.2-1ubuntu1. The pen is working but no touch functionality. The side buttons don't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I hate directing you to another site, but there was a really useful thread about installing Wacom Bamboo tablets (both pen and pen&touch models) on the ubuntuforums.org site, you should check that out.  I've gotten the Wacom Bamboo Pen version to work flawlessly on Lucid with the instructions in that thread.

[Ubuntu Forums .org - HOW TO Set Up the Bamboo Pen & Touch in Lucid](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562)

** EDIT **  I think you should only follow the first post or so in that thread, rather than follow the rest of the community's posts.  Favux knows more about this than anyone else.  If you have an issue with his setup procedures, send him a PM, he's very open to providing one-on-one assitance over privmsgs.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.